# Display Assembly Version from GlobalAssemblyInfo C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I have got several projects in one solution, so that I have used a **GlobalAssemblyFile** to maintain the Versioning.
But how do I display the Assembly version number from the **GlobalAssemblyInfo** file.

I have used this code to display but it displays the version as 0.0.0.0

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the fileVersion, and not the Assmblyversion in the GlobalAssemblyGile?

Comment: yes i have set the version as 1.0.* in GlobalAssemblyInfo file.